# Next JS with react-intl creates an ancestry issue

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-intl

I'm trying to setup NEXT Js with `react-intl`.

I've added to my `_app.tsx` the setup for react-intl as follows:

```js
import { IntlProvider } from 'react-intl';
import English from "../../lang/compiled-locales/en-US.json"
import French from "../../lang/compiled-locales/fr.json"
import configs from '../../configs';

// https://itnext.io/next-js-react-intl-add-internationalisation-to-your-nextjs-app-4f933104b1f7
const MyApp = ({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) => {
    const { locale } = useRouter()

    const messages = useMemo(() => {
        switch (locale) {
            case "fr":
                return French
            default:
                return English
        }
    }, [locale])

    return <IntlProvider
        locale={locale || configs.languages.default}
        messages={messages}>
        <Component {...pageProps} />
    </IntlProvider>
}

export default MyApp
```

When I ran it, it worked like a charm, but when I do a page reload, I get the following error:

```
Server Error
Error: [React Intl] Could not find required `intl` object. <IntlProvider> needs to exist in the component ancestry.

This error happened while generating the page. Any console logs will be displayed in the terminal window.
```

I'm guessing it's something to do with SSR but no idea how to fix. Thank you in advance for your help.

Here is the sample usage in my `pages/index.tsx`

```js
import type { NextPage } from 'next'
import Head from 'next/head'
import { FormattedMessage } from 'react-intl'
import Header from '../components/Header'

const Home: NextPage = () => {

    return <div className="">
        <Head>
            <title><FormattedMessage defaultMessage="FlipFlip - Print your videos for real!" id="landing.seo.title" /></title>
        </Head>

        <Header />
    </div>
}

export default Home
```

Comment: Give a try to use [react-intl-universal](https://fe-tool.com/react-intl-universal) with next.js. Here is an example [integrating react-intl-universal with NextJS](https://github.com/alibaba/react-intl-universal/tree/master/packages/react-intl-universal/examples/browser-example)